# Sorting a file's data list in python to compute a student's grade

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a function that would compute a student's (or netId's) grades. One grade would be the total potential points (which listed is line 3), the student's actual score, and then a weighted score (percent weight is line 2).

After opening and reading the file in python, how would I start to do this?

```
______________________________________________
netId   labs    hw  exams   final project
    .15 .2  .45     .2
    250 80  300     100
perfect1    250 80  300     100
aaa543  150 60  200     80
bbb999  200 80  180     45
ccc876  230 71  235     79
tnoah   240 78  295     94
rpolansk    130 25  100     38
ppan1234    200 64  240     80
______________________________________________
```

(How the text file is oriented)

[image]

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or code-writing resource.  It appears that what you need is some tutorial help on problem analysis, rather than SO.

Comment: The easiest way (fewest code) would be to use `pandas`. Try `read_csv`. You could also read the file into lists and do more by hand. For that look up `open`, `split` commands and read up on lists.  Try something  and repost where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

A simple start to solving your problem might be getting the data into a 2 dimensional array, or grid of sorts.

```
grid = [row.split() for row in text.split("\n")]
```

Now you can access the string value of a "cell" by using `grid[row_num][col_num]`